# celery task not retrying

Tags: python, celery

I have a simple test_celery.py file with the following contents that is not re-running a failed task:

```
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Celery(
    'test_celery',
    broker='amqp://',
    backend='amqp'
)

@app.task(retries=4)
def my_fail():
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception as e:
      print('Tring: {0}/{1}'.format(my_fail.request.retries, my_fail.max_retries))
      # Print log message with current retry
      my_fail.retry(exc=e, max_retries=4, countdown=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fail()
    print('All done!')
```

Unfortunately when I run the task, it just runs once:

```
$ python test_celery.py
Tring: 0/3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_celery.py", line 20, in <module>
    my_fail()
  File "/Users/alexgray/.virtualenvs/clearcare/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 191, in __call__
    return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/alexgray/.virtualenvs/clearcare/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 380, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "test_celery.py", line 17, in my_fail
    my_fail.retry(exc=e, max_retries=4, countdown=2)
  File "/Users/alexgray/.virtualenvs/clearcare/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 653, in retry
    raise_with_context(exc or Retry('Task can be retried', None))
  File "test_celery.py", line 13, in my_fail
    raise Exception()
Exception
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#using-a-custom-retry-delay), I think what you want is to actually raise the retry call.

```
def my_fail():
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception as e:
      print('Tring: {0}/{1}'.format(my_fail.request.retries, my_fail.max_retries))
      # Print log message with current retry
      raise my_fail.retry(exc=e, max_retries=4, countdown=2)
```

Notice that we raise the error, rather than just calling the task.

Comment: You are right. I also had to call it like my_fail.delay() in main, not my_fail()